# javascript lowercase onchange

Tags: javascript, onchange, lowercase, keyup

I hope you can help me with a little problem. I'm not getting anywhere.

If an entry is made in the field post_title, the characters should be copied automatically into the field post_uri. That works.

Now all letters should be lowercase automatically and spaces should be replaced by the - character.

What do I have to do?

```js
  $(function() {
    var $post_title = $('#post_title');
    var $post_uri = $('#post_uri');

    function onChange() {
      $post_uri.val($post_title.val());

    };
    $('#post_title')
      .change(onChange)
      .keyup(onChange);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="post_title" id="post_title">
  <input type="text" name="post_uri" id="post_uri">
</form>
```

Comment: call toLowerCase() ???

Comment: [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Comment: yes i know ... 

var $post_title = post_title.toLowerCase();

does not work

Comment: var $post_title = post_title.replace(' ',/-/g).toLowerCase()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. You only need to add `toLowerCase` and `replace` function calls on your string.

```js
$(function() {
    var $post_title = $('#post_title');
    var $post_uri = $('#post_uri');

    function onChange() {
      var val = $post_title.val().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "-");     
      $post_uri.val(val);

    };
    $('#post_title')
      .change(onChange)
      .keyup(onChange);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="post_title" id="post_title">
  <input type="text" name="post_uri" id="post_uri">
</form>
```

**EDIT:** Just for clarification, this solution does work in any situation where content is modified.

According to [jQuery's Docs](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

> `.change()`
>
> For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred **until the element loses focus.**

Comment: Just an additional note.  This solution doesn't work if pasting text via right mouse click.  It does work if pasting via `CTRL-V`

Answer (score 0):

**Variables**

---

Suppose this is your post title

> How to Setup Windows 10

I think you are trying to make your url like `example.com/how-to-setup-windows-10`.

**Code**

---

> Try this code I think it will work.

```
var space_url = $("#post_title").val().replace(" ", "-");
$("#post_url").val(space_url.toLowerCase());
```